# How do autopopulate splice(index start, end) by using search or match?

Tags: javascript

```
var Names = ["Smith", "Jones", "Jack", "Paul", "King"];
var Kings = [];
var allOthers = [];

alert (Names);
allOthers = Names;
```

//Here Javascript should do a search for the name `King`, if it finds it in the
array `allOthers`, then it //should move it to the array `Kings`. I tried using Search and match, but I couldn't get it to work.

//In the next line of code I am giving the slice method the index of the string `King` but it should 
//automatically populate the index of the name `King` in the array `allOthers` and 
move it to the //`Kings` array. How can this be accomplished?

```
Kings = Names.splice(4,1);

alert (Kings);
alert (allOthers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of "King" using `indexOf` and use that in your `splice`. Also, `splice` modifies the original array, so your `Names` is already modified to be "allOthers"

```
var names, kings;
names = ["Smith", "Jones", "Jack", "Paul", "King"];

if(names.indexOf('King') > -1){
  kings = names.splice(names.indexOf('King'),1);
}
console.log(kings); // ["King"]
console.log(names); // ["Smith", "Jones", "Jack", "Paul"]
```